# How to get data via Facebook api & FQL from a url (page fan)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have for example a fan page url (http://www.facebook.com/Microsoft).

I want to get via this url, data about the page - I mean name, likes, pic.. (What I can get from the table `page`).

I thought to do something like that:

```
SELECT name FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM ?? WHERE url = http://www.facebook.com/Microsoft)
```

But I dont know where I can get a page_id by url.. any suggestions?

**I have to use FQL**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the ID from url's, use the `object_url` table:

`SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url = "http://www.facebook.com/Microsoft"`

returns

```
[
  {
    "id": 20528438720
  }
]
```

Once you have that, you can use it to query the page using the ID.

`SELECT name,pic,fan_count FROM page WHERE page_id = "20528438720"`

returns

```
[
  {
    "name": "Microsoft",
    "pic": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/195730_20528438720_693767_s.jpg",
    "fan_count": 702319
  }
]
```

If you only want to query url's which are under Facebook, i.e. profiles, then use the profile table instead and get rid of the url, and use the username instead:

```
SELECT id,name,url,pic FROM profile WHERE username = "Intel"

[
  {
    "id": 22707976849,
    "name": "Intel",
    "url": "http://www.facebook.com/Intel",
    "pic": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/203507_22707976849_6594669_s.jpg"
  }
]
```

Comment: I tried it, but try "Intel" instead of "Microsoft" and it won't work, I really dont know why (It doesn't return ID).

Comment: Microsoft has their website as a Facebook page: http://graph.facebook.com/microsoft where as intel http://graph.facebook.com/intel doesn't

Comment: Have to be an option to get data via url from any fan page.. no? the way from the table object_url doen't help me a guess..

Comment: @Luis If you are just using url's that are under Facebook, check my updated answer.

Comment: But now I see there isn't an option to get likes, am I wrong? I can use one more query to each page to get fan_count.. but maybe its too much queries.

Comment: Never mined, I used it finally: SELECT fan_count, name, pic FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT id FROM profile WHERE username = 'Microsoft')